# httpd won't start on boot

Tags: centos, httpd, start, boot

I have some problemes with apache on CENTOS...

When I reboot the system, httpd won't start

I have to execut my-self "service httpd start"

```
chkconfig  httpd --list
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you!

Comment: What run level are you running in?

Based upon that output of `chkconfig` it looks like it should be starting the service if you're in run level 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal window an enter the following:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

This will start apache

then

```
tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

This will give you the last 10 entries in the apache log. There, you should find the error. Get it and paste it here.

Comment: I got 
[notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
[notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: He's already stated that he has to execute a `service httpd start` - that has the same effect as /etc/init.d/httpd start.